How to add specific audiences to a token for a token exchange in Keycloak?
I want to implement token exchange between two internal clients, but I keep getting the error that the audience is not within scope. I'm in v24. I have client A, client B, and client X. Client X has full scope allowed so in the token audience the other two clients appear, so I'm able to successfully exchange a client X token (obtained via oauth2) for a client A or client B token, using the request below.
return this.client.grant({
    grant_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:token-exchange",
    client_id: client (A or B) id,
    client_secret: client (A or B) secret,
    subject_token: client Z accessToken,
    subject_token_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:access_token",
    requested_token_type: "urn:ietf:params:oauth:token-type:refresh_token",
    scope: "openid email profile"
});

The access token I get from client A or B only contain themselves as audiences, and I can't exchange one for the other. I'm trying to exchange client A's access token for a client B access token. I tried to configure the audience in the token via a an audience mapper and also tried the official documentation steps, but this documentation seems outdated, a lot of the steps are not clear or seem incomplete.
Most of the info I found in StackOverflow is about impersonation which is not what I need, and in the Keycloak Slack my questions go usually not replied. Even documentation that seemed relevant is returning a 404.
I've tried adding my special scope to the grant request, it doesn't change anything. I tried adding the "audience" parameter to my grant request, but this only works for me as a string, so even though the RFC documentation says it should accept an array, I haven't managed to pass one successfully (I get Bad Request: OPError: invalid_request (duplicated parameter when I try). I have tried using the client_id and secret of the origin client instead of the target client, but this doesn't seem to work, I just get a token from the origin client, not the target one.
So, I have many many questions:

What's the best way of having client B as an audience in client A token?
in the call, what should the scope be
in the call, should I pass an audience parameter and if so what should it be
in the call, are the client id and secret supposed to be the ones for client A (origin) or client B (target)?

I would like to be able to do the token exchange without having to grant full scope to clients A and B, but I don't know what I'm missing. Any pointers to token exchange between internal clients code examples would be very welcome!
